# With adjective uses of the to-infinitive like 'a place to live in', is the preposition 'in' necessary?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, infinitives, intransitive-verbs

- a house to live in
- a place to live in

Does the second example essentially need the preposition 'in'?

In the first example, the noun 'house' is a specific place, so I've known to use to-infinitive it needs a preposition.

But the second noun is nonspecific, common.
Then doesn't it need a preposition at all?
Or is it okay to use a preposition?

Comment: No, _a place to live_ specifically doesn't need a preposition, because it is a fixed phrase. _Live_ requires a locative phrase, and the preposition doesn't add anything but locative marking, which is already there with _place_.

Comment: I would say *a place to live* is common but informal. Since one cannot *live a place*, in less informal language, you'd need *in*.

Comment: @Cerberus-ReinstateMonica People who need glasses to see aren't ones who see glasses. :)

Comment: @Cerberus-ReinstateMonica — I don't think anyone would ever say — formally or informally — *I need a place to live in.*

Comment: No, the prep "in" is superfluous. Note that "to live" is a infinitival relative clause modifying "house" / "place".

Comment: To me "a place to live in" suggests a building (something you are inside), while "a place to live" could be a town or country. Same with "a place to go" vs "a place to go in".

Comment: @tchrist: That is true: the infinitive in *I need glasses to see* may be seen as modifying the verb/praedicate rather than *glasses* only. When you change the verb to *these are glasses to see*, you can feel that it becomes somewhat less fluent, because the verb *be* does not use a *to* infinitive the same way *need* can.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: Right, and I would say that is because the whole expression is informal, isn't it?

Comment: @Cerberus-ReinstateMonica — *I need a place to live* doesn't sound informal to me (American English).

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I think even using the word *place* to indicate a house (or building functioning as such) sounds less than formal to me?

Answer (score 1):

This is, as Lawler notes, a fixed phrase. But it works with other infinitives also: you can say "a place to eat" but not *"a park to eat" or *"I eat the place."

Essentially, "a place to live" means "a (suitable) place for living," just as "a place to eat" means "a (suitable) place for eating."

Comment: Note that although _to live_ is a relative infinitive (it's a compressed version of the relative clause _where one can live_ and clearly modifies _place_), it can't use a relative pronoun: *_a place where to live_. Relative infinitives don't allow them unless they're pied-piped: _a place in which to live_ but  not *_a place which to live in_. And certainly not *_a place which to live._